# How to combine several pages resulted from HTTP requests and jQuery scripts into one?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a page that displays user information as a result of a HTTP request. This user page has a print button.  On clicking onto this print button the information is formatted for printout using jQuery scripts.

Now I have a task to print several users.  I can send an AJAX request for every user, put results into a separate div for every user, invoke a print button for every div, and then display results.

My concern is that the results for every page will have the same id (i.e. “container”) – this will screw up jQuery scripts.

How to fix this design, or maybe there is a better design idea?

Comment: I can suggest 2 options. 1) Create containers with unique IDs, perhaps by means of embedding user ids (not actual user IDs) into divs' IDs, for example, "container_43234", "container_685", etc. and process each of them as soon as it arrives; 2) Do not rely on IDs at all, instead wait for all containers and when they are ready, read them as an array, a-la `$('.container')`, and then add class (for example `processed`) for every instance while printing them in foreach loop.

Comment: It is interesting, thank you. However, this solution will require rewriting all existent scripts – too much work and testing. What about using frames or dummy pages and then combining those stripping IDs?

Comment: If you provide some code to get a notion about your current scripts, this could help to think adherent to your implementation. But I don't think fake frames or pages are better than plain javascript solution.

Comment: The idea is not to modify the current scripts, i.e. $('#nav').hide();
 $('#sidebar').hide();
 $('#subNav').hide();. Is it possible?

Comment: You can write another script, which will automate and repeat the process for a set of user pages, much like Selenium or CasperJS does. After every iteration you can clean up results from previous iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that my concern about ID’s was not relevant.
All responses from AJAX requests can be added to the total result div  by jQuery  append.   Despite responses have the same iD’s this does not prevent them to adding to the total result